# Maven Checksum Output to text file

Tags: maven

I currently have a maven project that is using a Nexus repository. I was wondering if there was a way that while Maven was downloading the jars/sha1/etc from the Nexus repository if it could output the checksums to a text file of some sort?

The ultimate goal is for a verifiable consistency check. I'd like to get it so there was a log file from Nexus with all of it's checksums and then I could create another log file with all of the checksums from the local repository and then cross check the two log files to verify they are the same. I realize that maven currently does something similar, but I'd like a way to physically show that they are the same for auditing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on errors instead of warning in case of wrong checksums via the checkSumPolicy in your settings.xml file.

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>codehausSnapshots</id>
          <name>Codehaus Snapshots</name>
          <releases>
            ..
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            ...
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
          <url>http://snapshots.maven.codehaus.org/maven2</url>
          <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
```

On other thing is important to configure nexus in the way not to recalculate the checksums new during download.

On the other hand if you like to create files with checksums you could check the [maven-checksum-plugin](http://nicoulaj.github.com/maven-checksum-plugin/index.html) which is intended to create such files for a project.

Comment: Is there any way to output that the check sums matched? It would be even better if the checksums actually were outputted. Is that what the checksum plugin does? I'll take a look at it

Comment: If the checksum does not match the build will fail. The checksumplugin only creates for the current project such thing.

Comment: It doesn't really appear that the checksum plugin is doing what I hoped it would do. Is there not a way for the checksum check to be exported. We need to be able to show 100% that the file that was downloaded from the server is the same one that is now on the local drive

Thanks again for your help

Comment: Not that i know. The configuration option checksumPolicy will make sure exactly that otherwise the build will fail which indicates the files are different.

Comment: Just wish there was a way for that checksumPolicy to output it's checks to a log file that way if someone needs proof that it completed the process they could check through the log files and see that all of the checksums matched.